# Ef Core, many-to-many connection table composite key with different datatypes

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

How do i ensure a composite key of two properties with different datatypes? EF Core complains that;

***The relationship from 'GroupUsers.Groups' to 'Group.GroupUsers' with foreign key properties {'UserId' : string} cannot target the primary key {'GroupId' : int} because it is not compatible. Configure a principal key or a set of compatible foreign key properties for this relationship.***

My tables are a many to many relationship with primary keys that differ in types as below

```
public class Group
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int GroupId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string GroupName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<GroupUsers> GroupUsers { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    [Key]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public ICollection<GroupUsers> GroupUsers { get; set; }
}

public class GroupUsers
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public int GroupId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("GroupId")]
    public Group Groups { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public User Users { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the Fluent side of things i forgot to show

```
     modelBuilder.Entity<GroupUsers>().HasKey(gu => new { gu.GroupId, gu.UserId});
     modelBuilder.Entity<GroupUsers>().HasOne(ub => ub.Users)
            .WithMany(x => x.GroupUsers).HasForeignKey(h => h.GroupId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);

      modelBuilder.Entity<GroupUsers>().HasOne(ub => ub.Groups)
            .WithMany(x => x.GroupUsers).HasForeignKey(h => h.UserId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

Comment: Something is missing in the picture. Can you post the fluent configuration?

Comment: The composite key isn't the problem. The foreign key relationship is wrong somehow, as evidenced by **{'UserId' : string}** being matched to **{'GroupId' : int}**.  As an aside, your `GroupUsers` navigation properties need to be `virtual`.

Comment: I've added to the question a glimpse of how am trying to accomplish it with FluentAPI.

Comment: Your `HasForeignKey` calls are switched.

Comment: @madreflection where do i mark you as the right answer? It took me a while to realize that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having seen your fluent configuration, it looks like your `HasForeignKey` calls are switched.

It should be:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<GroupUsers>().HasKey(gu => new { gu.GroupId, gu.UserId});
modelBuilder.Entity<GroupUsers>().HasOne(ub => ub.Users)
    .WithMany(x => x.GroupUsers).HasForeignKey(h => h.UserId)  // <-- change to this
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);

modelBuilder.Entity<GroupUsers>().HasOne(ub => ub.Groups)
    .WithMany(x => x.GroupUsers).HasForeignKey(h => h.GroupId)  // <-- change to this
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```